# Understanding information about threads in Android Studio

Tags: android, multithreading, android-studio

During debugging on a breakpoint one can notice on the left of the Debug panel a dropdown list which lists various threads in the following format:

```
"main"@3,573 in group "main":WAIT
"pool-1-thread-1"@3,665 in group "main":WAIT
```

I have the following questions:

1) What does the four digit number mean (e.g. `3,573`)? Process number?

2) What is meant here by `group`?

Answer (score 1):

The thread display is defined by the UI.

If you are using Intellij @### is the line number.
You can customize this in "Customize Thread View"

[image]

From the Thread class documentation:

State: 
   http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.State.html

Thread Groups:
 https://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA288&lpg=PA288&dq=Avoid+thread+groups&source=bl&ots=yZGnRmr6P3&sig=qH791dt7d0PrPeG7D5SH-4Yzg3Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjK2e7DgbvJAhXETCYKHRoFAMIQ6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=Avoid%20thread%20groups&f=false

Comment: The number cannot be thread id. Different threads can have the same value for the number.

Comment: Anything else you'd like to add to your answer apart from links?

Comment: Line number of what? Of a source code file? Which source then? Also, could you answer according to points listed in the question so that further readers could understand it better.